# Will C++17 support the simpler Range-based For Loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Since C++11, we can write:

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
for (auto x : v)
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

According to [Essentials of Modern C++ Style](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Back%20to%20the%20Basics!%20Essentials%20of%20Modern%20C%2B%2B%20Style/Back%20to%20the%20Basics!%20Essentials%20of%20Modern%20C%2B%2B%20Style%20-%20Herb%20Sutter%20-%20CppCon%202014.pdf), the following code will soon be also legal in C++:

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
for (x : v)
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Will this feature be available in C++17 or C++20?

Comment: No, it will not. That being said, in my opinion, this is not simpler, but rather more confusing.

Comment: @DeiDei Citation needed. So far, it's just your word against Herb Sutter's.

Comment: @hvd And who doesn't trust the Herb

Comment: @DeiDei, http://ideone.com/KONqTW

Comment: @hvd it is the word of someone in 2016 against the word of someone in 2014...

Comment: @Qwertiy Neither latest GCC, nor Clang compile the code you've linked. Plus, the above syntax doesn't appear in any previous standard document, nor the current draft standard. I wouldn't count on this.

Comment: @DeiDei, ideone uses g++, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Which is still not interesting and not enough to answer the question.

Comment: @Qwertiy Okay, after some more research... The compiler used by Ideone is GCC 5.1 which allows this syntax with -std=c++1z. This is not allowed anymore since GCC 6.1.

Comment: @DeiDei, thank you.

Comment: I'm with @DeiDei here for sure. Let's not forget, Herb is also the guy (IIRC) who advocates "almost always auto". He's not infallible :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No. This was killed by the committee [more than two years ago](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html#CWG15), mostly because of concerns about potential confusion caused by shadowing:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int x = 0; 
for(x : v) {} // this declares a new x, and doesn't use x from the line above
assert(x == 0); // holds
```

The objections came up so late in the process that both Clang and GCC had already implemented the feature by the time it got rejected by the full committee. The implementations were eventually backed out: [Clang](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=222865) [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=229632)

Comment: Eh? https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#81 is still open and says "Author is going to revise".

Comment: @hvd The EWG issues list hasn't been updated in more than a year. IIRC STL is not actively working on any revision. In any event, it seems clear that the committee isn't going to accept anything that doesn't somehow resemble a declaration at the minimum.

Comment: Oh... that's really unfortunate regardless of the merits of the proposal. It's important to keep such lists up to date.

Comment: By the way, [is such code valid](http://ideone.com/W7OOXE) and what it should output?

Comment: @Qwertiy That's a wholly different question, but no, that's not valid. The syntax for the range-based `for` requires a declaration, not merely an expression.

Comment: If I were to write code like this, I would *want* it to use the outside x. This is a common pattern with languages that do allow this (including traditional for loops in C/C++) Is there any chance of this becoming legal in a future version?

Comment: Another good example of why compilers should hold off until standardisation, IMO. Although, okay, granted, you had to use `-std=c++1z` so maybe fair enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: On the other hand, the standardization process benefits greatly from implementation experience. Since it's easier to remove something from a compiler (especially when hidden behind a nonstandard flag) than from the standard, I think the right thing happened here.

Comment: @ruakh: That's true

Answer (score 4):

This is still [an open issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#81). There was a proposal, linked there, to add this to C++17. [That proposal was rejected](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html). Whether a new proposal will be accepted depends on the proposal, so it's too soon to say whether C++20 might have it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Update**
>
> GCC 5.1 allows this syntax with -std=c++1z.
>   This is not allowed anymore since GCC 6.1.
>
> So this answer doesn't seem to be correct.

Ideone compiler successfully compiles such code under C++ 14:

http://ideone.com/KONqTW

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (x : v)
        cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like it *is* available, but that it *was* available for a while, but no longer.